# i cant load image when use Mobile device,so i need to refresh the page

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

Before Refresh (Scroll Down) -> After Refresh
[image: Before Refresh (Scroll Down) -> After Refresh]

Comment: i think you must describe your problem with detail like code or something. Goodluck!!

Answer (score 0):

Hey there am thinking this could be happened because of image size. If this could be true then please use lazyload function/script for than image could easily load-

```
<img src="celebration.jpg" loading="lazy" alt="..." />
```

2. Also you can try to change the format of image to webp so that size of image could shrink and server easily handle that.
3. You can try to reset cache-

Hope you like it.